# Check if string is a valid file name and path without Regx in angular Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, filenames, filepath

I am trying to see if a string is a valid file name and path. Right now I am using regex to do it but seems after typing a longer length of string it uses lots of CPU and makes the browser to be un-progressive.

```
 public static readonly INVALID_FILE_NAME_REGEX: RegExp = /([a-zA-Z0-9 _@\-^!#$%&+={}./\\\[\]]+)+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

and I use test to check it

```
INVALID_FILE_NAME_REGEX.test(myFilePath);
```

I was wondering if there is any way to check the file name and path is correct without Regex, or something does not use lots of resources?

here is example of valid and invalid paths.

invalid

```
path/
/path
/path/folder
/path/
```

valid

```
file.txt
/path/folder/file.txt
file.TXT
```

Thanks

Comment: Define valid file path.

Comment: You'll probably make it a lot faster just by adding a ^ anchor to the beginning.  You can also remove the left and right parens.... that's not adding anything.  Also you have an extra +.... one inside the parens and one outside the parens!. Man I bet that's causing a performance problem... I added an answer

Comment: another point... a more accurate variable name would be VALID_FILE_NAME_REGEX not INVALID_FILE_NAME_REGEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _@\-^!#$%&+={}./\\\[\]]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wiht this, it worked for me.

^([\/][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[\/]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Example 1:
https://rubular.com/r/S7QydSU6jnuCLd

Example 2:
https://rubular.com/r/sYARkEfsDJO15f

This page helps you to check you RegExp